# Плохое качество теней

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android

[image: Модель в blender]

Импортировал из blender 3д модель хорошего качества. Поставил в нужное место, поставил Directional Light. И качество теней очень плохое, где можно регулировать их, чтобы не особо калечили производительность? Сборка будет под Android.

[image: Отображение модели в Unity]

Answer (score 1):

Ну собственно вот разрешение карты теней, для каждого источника своя настройка у Вас стоит параметр "брать из настроек качества", это меню перед запуском игры, где пользователю предлагается выбрать один из нескольких готовых пресетов, но это на десктопе, как дела обстоят на андроиде - бог его знает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выберите тут [image: highest]

---

Потом на Вашем скрине видно что у Вас стоит масштабирование игрового окна:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения],

Масштабирование делает картинку в закладке `game` зернистой, это лупа, чтобы пиксели рассматривать

Comment: Ну, я приблизил для наглядности, без зума так же. На Андроиде при запуске игры, сразу показывает эту модель, без настроек графики.